# JButton с иконкой над background'ом

Tags: java, изображения

Делая простую игру на Java столкнулся с проблемой как сделать кнопку, в которой кроме рисунка и надписи больше ничего не должно быть видно, так как она стоит поверх canvas на котором прорисовуется все содержимое. Пробовал сделать нечто подобное:

```
public class Menu{
...
public open(){
    JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonImage));
    button.setBounds(100, 400, 300, 100);
    button.setOpaque(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
    Display.addButton(button);
        }
    }
}
...
public class Display{
    private static JFrame window;
...
//Создание окна и добавление canvas
...
    public static void addButton(JButton btn){
        window.getLayeredPane().add(btn,JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        window.revalidate();
        }
...
}
```

Но получилась кнопка с рисунком и белым фоном позади:
[image: button on the background]
Пробовал также создавать кнопку через переопределение метода `paint()` но результат получался почти таким же. Можно как-то сделать кнопку( как наследника `JComponent`) чтобы не было видно её границ?

Comment: а на каком движке делаете игру?

Comment: попробуйте так `button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`

Comment: ничего не изменилось)

Comment: Если у вас в самом изображении нет прозрачного фона, то в java его тоже не будет, проще всего сделать изображение с прозрачным фоном.

Comment: 1) изображение имеет прозрачный фон; 2) решил просто сделать изображение кнопки которое реагирует на нажатие, и изменяется при нажатии.